transfinite induction and what things you are allowed to assume
I'm learning about transfinite induction and well-ordered sets for the first time, and I'm a bit confused on exactly how transfinite induction works when defining the existence of a function.
Specifically, I'm working on the problem that if we have well ordered sets $J,C$ and there exists no surjective mapping of a section of $J$ onto $C$ then there exists a unique function $h: J \to C$ given by:
$$h(x) = \min[C- h(S_x)]$$
I am hoping someone can tell me is this approach is correct. Let $\mathcal{F}$ the class of functions having a section of $J$ as a domain, and $C$ as the co-domain. Then define $\psi: \mathcal{F} \to C$ given by $\psi(f) = \min[C - f(S_x)]$ for $f \in \mathcal{F}$ having $S_x$ as its domain, and $\psi$ is well defined by the assumption. Then let $X \subset J$ be the largest subset of $J$ on which there exists a function $h: X \to C$ such that:
$$h(x) = \psi(h_{|S_x}) = \min[C- h(S_x)]$$
Then take $x \in X$ (and $X$ is non-empty since it contains $\min[J]$ and its successor and so on), and also $S_x \subset X$ since by assumption $h_{|S_x}$ exists*. Then it follows that $X = S_y$ for some $y \in J$ or $X=J$**. But if $X=S_y$ then we can define $h':X \cup\{y\} \to C$ as $h'(y) = \psi(h_{|S_y})$ (and $h'_{|X}=h$), so we conclude that $X=J$.
There are two parts of this I am not sure about, denoted by *, and **. For * is this ok to do? Basically my idea is we define $X$ as a set where such an $h$ exists, and then in order for this to be true, it must be that if $x\in X$ then $S_x \subset X$. But this feels like a strong conclusion to get. For ** I think it is true that for any set having the property that $x \in A \implies S_x \subset A$, then either $A$ is a section of $A$ is the whole set, but not completely sure.

Your idea is sound, but I think there are a few spots where you need to be a bit more careful.
For instance, you say

Let $X\subset J$ be the largest subset of $J$ on which there exists a function $h$ such that, for all $x\in X$,
$$ h(x) = \psi(h_{|S_x}) = \min[C- h(S_x)] \tag{$\ast$}$$

There are a couple of assumptions that underlie this:

There is a set $Y$ (not necessarily the largest one, more on this below) on which such a function $h$ exists, i.e. $\text{dom}(h)=Y$. This is trivial, because the empty set has this property. The same is true about the singleton $\{\min(J)\}$.
When writing $(\ast)$, you probably want the domain of $h$ to be downwards closed, because that will ensure that $h$ is defined on all of $S_x$ whenever $x\in\text{dom}(f)$. Here, $Y$ being downwards closed says $S_x\subset Y$ whenever $x\in Y$.
This is possibly the harder bit: you're assuming that, among all the sets $Y$ which are the domains of functions $h$ satisfying $(*)$, there is one that is the largest one. In general, a family of sets need not have a largest element, so there's something special going on here.

Given all this, let's restate things to accommodate these details:

Let $\mathfrak{Y}$ be the family of all sets $Y\subset J$ such that $Y$ is downwards closed and there exists a function $h:Y\to C$ such that, for all $y\in Y$,
$$h(y)=\psi(h|_{S_y})\tag{$**$}$$

By what you've said, the set $\mathfrak{Y}$ has non-empty elements. I now claim that $\mathfrak{Y}$ has a $(\subset)$-largest element $X$. How do we find it? Well, there's only one candidate, namely $X:=\bigcup\mathfrak{Y}$. The key here is to verify that $X\in\mathfrak{Y}$. So, you need to verify that $X$ is downwards closed (I leave this to you) and produce a function $h$ with domain $X$ satisfying $(**)$. The temptation here is to just paste together the different functions $h_Y$ for $Y\in\mathfrak{Y}$, but there's a tiny wrinkle: the union of a family of functions need not be a function. The way around this is to argue the following:

First, show that for every $Y\in\mathfrak{Y}$ there is exactly one function $h$ satisfying $(**)$. Try to prove this. Hint: suppose there were two such functions and find a minimal point on which they disagree.
Use the uniqueness clause (1) to show that, if $Y\subset Z$ are both in $\mathfrak{Y}$, then $h_Y=h_Z|_Y$.

This will let you conclude that $\bigcup_{Y\in\mathfrak{Y}}h_Y$ is a function with domain $X$. Now you just need to argue that it satisfies $(**)$.
The second half of the argument, showing that $X=J$, is as you've outlined in your question.

Thank you for this answer, this is very helpful. How does this sounds? Regarding (1), for a single domain $Y$ clearly there is only one $h$ satisfying (**). For (2), given $Y,Z \in \mathfrak{Y}$ wlog let $Y \subset Z$ (since a downward closed set is a section or all of $J$). And then if there is a minimal point on which they disagree we have a contradiction. Then $\bigcup_{Y \in \mathfrak{Y}} h_Y$ is in $X$ because each element $x \in X$ falls into a series of nested sections and $h$ is the same on all of these.

@tree3498 For (1), it depends on what you mean by "clearly". The argument I had in mind involves showing that a minimal element of ${x\in Y:h(x)\neq h'(x)}$ would be contradictory (where $h$ and $h'$ are witnesses to $Y\in\mathfrak{Y}$), by $(**)$. If something like that is what you had in mind, then great! What I want to emphasize is that, while the argument isn't hard, some argument is needed.
